# Vector proof for a tetrahedron.

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let $OABC$ be a regular tetrahedron. Using   $OA=a,~OB=b,~OC=c$, prove that  $QT$  bisects  $PU$ where $P,U,Q,T$ are mid points on the edges of a regular tetrahedron. P is the midpoint of OA. T is the midpoint of AC. U is the midpoint of BC. Q is the midpoint of OB. Midpoints; P and Q are midpoints on the edges of the base of the tetrahedron.

Going about this I thought that I would prove that $PUQT$ forms a a parallelogram and then prove that $QT$ bisects $PU$, however I may be wrong.

Comment: Are $P, Q, U, T$ the midpoints of the four triangular faces?

Comment: no, p, q, u, t are the midpoints of four of the five edges of the regular tetrahedron.

Comment: But a tetrahedron has six edges.

Comment: sorry, typo i meant to say six

Comment: Can you please specify in an edit which four of the sides $OA, OB, OC, AB, AC, BC$ have which of $P, Q, U, T$ as midpoints? There are several different ways to do it, and not all of them will let $PU$ and $QT$ intersect.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

if the leght of the side is $l$, we have:
$$
O=(0,0,0) \quad A=(l,0,0) \quad B=(\dfrac{l}{2},\dfrac{l\sqrt{3}}{2},0) \quad C=(\dfrac{l}{2},\dfrac{l\sqrt{3}}{2},\dfrac{l\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}})
$$
and we find:
$$
P=(\dfrac{l}{2},0,0) \quad Q=(\dfrac{l}{4},\dfrac{l\sqrt{3}}{4},0)
$$
$$
T=(\dfrac{3l}{4},\dfrac{l\sqrt{3}}{4},\dfrac{l\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{3}}) \quad U=(\dfrac{l}{2},\dfrac{l\sqrt{3}}{2},\dfrac{l\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{3}})
$$
Now it is easy to show that the midpoint of $PU$ coincide with the midpoint of $QT$. And you can put all this in a nice vector form if you want.

Comment: I think you get friendlier numbers is you use $s=\ell/\sqrt2$, and rotate the tetrahedron so that $O=(0,0,0)$, $A=(s,s,0)$, $B=(s,0,s)$ and $C=(0,s,s)$. This is what I was suggesting in my answer :-) +1 for working all this out, of course.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Good suggestion. But it's not so difficult also with my numbers.